# Dynamically update auto generated group-columns when groupMultiAutoColumn enabled

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Is there any way to update the properties of an auto-generated row-group column when you introduce an additional level of column grouping?

If I group on one column, I can use Grid API's `setAutoGroupColumnDef`, however when `groupMultiAutoColumn` is enabled, I cannot share this definition across each auto-generated column

I've unsuccessfully tried using Grid API's `setColumnDefs` after getting all columns back from the Column API but these don't appear to be compatible with the Grid API and breaks my grid

The specific issue is that within my application we have application-level column types like number-only, checkbox, multi-select, etc. these have their own filters that work fine for a non-grouped column, but when the auto-generated row-group column is generated it defaults to the set-filter, which is not consistent with the non-grouped columns, thus I want to be able to dynamically apply `filter`, `filterParams`, `keyCreator` etc.

Comment: unclear what you're trying to achieve. What exactly do you want to update in your grouped columns?

Comment: @ViqMontana as I mentioned "specifically because I want to dynamically set the filter properties based on the (grouped) column type", eg within my application we have application-level column types like number-only, checkbox, multi-select, etc. these have their own filters that work fine for a non-grouped column, but when the auto-generated row-group column is generated it defaults to the set-filter, which is not appropriate

Comment: It seems "groupMultiAutoColumn" has been removed from the latest version (I'm trying v29 now)